# Прототип (отдельно) и конструктор (отдельно) на реальных примерах из сайтов?

Tags: javascript

Читал о конструкторах в функциях:

```
function Animal(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.canWalk = true;
}
var animal = new Animal("ёжик");
```

А также о прототипах:

```
Animal.prototype.draw = function () {
}
```

На этих ресурсах:

- learn.javascript.ru
- developer.mozilla.org

Но до конца не понял как именно они уменьшают код и в принципе улучшают жизнь программистам. ))

Почему?

Потому что лучше понимается на реальных примерах из сайтов а не на примерах animal или "ёжиках" всяких.

Пример из моего личного опыта:

Хорошо освоил циклы когда нужно было для 30 изображений прописать функцию но я вместо 30 функций передал одну функцию в цикл и уменьшил таким образом код, так я и понял всю суть цикла, а не просто заучил его анатомию.

Вот бы и на этих ресурсах делали примеры из реальных проектов новички не задавали бы по 100 однотипных вопросов. Хотя с точки зрения терминологии это классные ресурсы.

Поэтому у меня такие вопросы:

1. Можете ли вы написать здесь как выглядел бы код сначала **без прототипа** и затем **с прототипом** на каком-то маленьком примере из сайта?

Или пример который мог бы быть реализован на каком сайте

2. Можете ли вы написать здесь как выглядел бы код сначала **без конструктора** и затем **с конструктором** на каком-то маленьком примере из сайта?

Или пример который мог бы быть реализован на каком сайте

Comment: ваш вопрос о том, чем ООП лучше процедурного стиля. Дано вам средство, хотите используйте, хотите нет. Наличие инструмента не говорит о том, что его надо применять везде.

Comment: 1) https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js  (например Modal ) - даже отдельно https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/dist/modal.js